# Java spring boot cache generation in docker container fails

Tags: spring-boot, docker, jar, ehcache

Are there special configurations that have to be considered to run a java spring boot application inside Docker?

The [application](https://github.com/ehrbase/ehrbase) I try to run in a Docker container fails with errors related to cache generation ([full error log](https://gist.github.com/testautomation/78b69d2c03f3739f369eca6580e618fb)). Building and running the application without Docker works without any issues.

#### Quick-peek of some of the errors form the log:

```sh
2019-10-31 08:24:37.982  INFO 617 --- [           main] org.ehcache.xml.XmlConfiguration         : Loading Ehcache XML configuration from file:/usr/project/application/target/application-0.9.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/ehcache.xml.
2019-10-31 08:24:38.611  INFO 617 --- [           main] org.ehcache.jsr107.ConfigurationMerger   : Configuration of cache introspectCache will be supplemented by template heap-cache
2019-10-31 08:24:38.612  INFO 617 --- [           main] org.ehcache.jsr107.ConfigurationMerger   : Cache introspectCache will use expiry configuration from template heap-cache
2019-10-31 08:24:38.809  INFO 617 --- [           main] o.t.o.p.UpfrontAllocatingPageSource      : Allocating 200.0MB in chunks
2019-10-31 08:24:38.965  INFO 617 --- [           main] org.ehcache.core.EhcacheManager          : Cache 'introspectCache' created in EhcacheManager.
2019-10-31 08:24:38.978  INFO 617 --- [           main] org.ehcache.jsr107.ConfigurationMerger   : Configuration of cache templateCache will be supplemented by template heap-cache
2019-10-31 08:24:38.978  INFO 617 --- [           main] org.ehcache.jsr107.ConfigurationMerger   : Cache templateCache will use expiry configuration from template heap-cache
2019-10-31 08:24:38.986  INFO 617 --- [           main] o.t.o.p.UpfrontAllocatingPageSource      : Allocating 200.0MB in chunks
2019-10-31 08:24:39.095  INFO 617 --- [           main] org.ehcache.core.EhcacheManager          : Cache 'templateCache' created in EhcacheManager.
2019-10-31 08:24:39.098  INFO 617 --- [           main] org.ehcache.jsr107.ConfigurationMerger   : Configuration of cache operationaltemplateCache will be supplemented by template heap-cache
2019-10-31 08:24:39.098  INFO 617 --- [           main] org.ehcache.jsr107.ConfigurationMerger   : Cache operationaltemplateCache will use expiry configuration from template heap-cache
2019-10-31 08:24:39.110  INFO 617 --- [           main] o.t.o.p.UpfrontAllocatingPageSource      : Allocating 200.0MB in chunks
2019-10-31 08:24:41.206  WARN 617 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'contributionServiceImp' defined in URL [jar:file:/usr/project/application/target/application-0.9.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/service-0.9.0.jar!/org/ehrbase/service/ContributionServiceImp.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'knowledgeCacheService' defined in URL [jar:file:/usr/project/application/target/application-0.9.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/service-0.9.0.jar!/org/ehrbase/service/KnowledgeCacheService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cacheManagerCustomizer' defined in class path resource [org/ehrbase/configuration/CacheConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.cache.CacheManager]: Factory method 'cacheManagerCustomizer' threw exception; nested exception is org.ehcache.jsr107.MultiCacheException: [Exception 0] Cache 'operationaltemplateCache' creation in EhcacheManager failed.
2019-10-31 08:24:41.214  INFO 617 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2019-10-31 08:24:41.233  INFO 617 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2019-10-31 08:24:41.273  INFO 617 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-10-31 08:24:41.281 ERROR 617 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'contributionServiceImp' defined in URL [jar:file:/usr/project/application/target/application-0.9.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/service-0.9.0.jar!/org/ehrbase/service/ContributionServiceImp.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'knowledgeCacheService' defined in URL [jar:file:/usr/project/application/target/application-0.9.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/service-0.9.0.jar!/org/ehrbase/service/KnowledgeCacheService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cacheManagerCustomizer' defined in class path resource [org/ehrbase/configuration/CacheConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.cache.CacheManager]: Factory method 'cacheManagerCustomizer' threw exception; nested exception is org.ehcache.jsr107.MultiCacheException: [Exception 0] Cache 'operationaltemplateCache' creation in EhcacheManager failed.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
    at org.ehrbase.application.EhrBase.main(EhrBase.java:38)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'knowledgeCacheService' defined in URL [jar:file:/usr/project/application/target/application-0.9.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/service-0.9.0.jar!/org/ehrbase/service/KnowledgeCacheService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cacheManagerCustomizer' defined in class path resource [org/ehrbase/configuration/CacheConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.cache.CacheManager]: Factory method 'cacheManagerCustomizer' threw exception; nested exception is org.ehcache.jsr107.MultiCacheException: [Exception 0] Cache 'operationaltemplateCache' creation in EhcacheManager failed.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
    ... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cacheManagerCustomizer' defined in class path resource [org/ehrbase/configuration/CacheConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.cache.CacheManager]: Factory method 'cacheManagerCustomizer' threw exception; nested exception is org.ehcache.jsr107.MultiCacheException: [Exception 0] Cache 'operationaltemplateCache' creation in EhcacheManager failed.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
    ... 41 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.cache.CacheManager]: Factory method 'cacheManagerCustomizer' threw exception; nested exception is org.ehcache.jsr107.MultiCacheException: [Exception 0] Cache 'operationaltemplateCache' creation in EhcacheManager failed.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 54 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.ehcache.jsr107.MultiCacheException: [Exception 0] Cache 'operationaltemplateCache' creation in EhcacheManager failed.
    at org.ehcache.jsr107.Eh107CacheManager.createCache(Eh107CacheManager.java:205)
    at org.ehrbase.configuration.CacheConfiguration.buildCache(CacheConfiguration.java:64)
    at org.ehrbase.configuration.CacheConfiguration.cacheManagerCustomizer(CacheConfiguration.java:53)
    at org.ehrbase.configuration.CacheConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a4ce32f5.CGLIB$cacheManagerCustomizer$0(<generated>)
    at org.ehrbase.configuration.CacheConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a4ce32f5$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$b982cbd8.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358)
    at org.ehrbase.configuration.CacheConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a4ce32f5.cacheManagerCustomizer(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 55 common frames omitted

The command '/bin/sh -c sh -c "./docker_build_script.sh"' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

### Additional files that are not in the application's repo

Dockerfile

```
# postgres db container with some ehrbase customizations
FROM ehrbaseorg/ehrbase-database-docker:11.5

# you may need to adjust the IP address
ENV DB_URL="jdbc:postgresql://172.17.0.2:5432/ehrbase"
ENV DB_USER="postgres"
ENV DB_PASS="postgres"
ENV POSTGRES_USER="postgres"
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD="postgres"

# install java openjdk, maven
RUN apk add --no-cache openjdk8
RUN apk add --no-cache maven
RUN java -version
RUN mvn -version

# copy repo into container filesystem
WORKDIR /usr/project
COPY . .

RUN mkdir -p file_repo/knowledge/archetypes \
    &&  mkdir -p file_repo/knowledge/operational_templates \
    && mkdir -p file_repo/knowledge/templates

# Start Build Process
COPY ./docker_build_script.sh .
RUN chmod +x ./docker_build_script.sh
RUN sh -c "./docker_build_script.sh"

EXPOSE 8080
```

Shell script to start required processed inside the Docker container

```sh
#!/bin/bash

set -e

# Start DB
su - postgres -c "pg_ctl -D ${PGDATA} -w start && pg_ctl -D ${PGDATA} status"

mvn package
sleep 1
java -jar application/target/application-0.9.0.jar
```

I have put the full error log and steps to reproduce the issue into a Github Gist: [full error log](https://gist.github.com/testautomation/78b69d2c03f3739f369eca6580e618fb)

Any ideas how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that jumps out at me is that you're not setting `-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize` to anything specific. This means it defaults to the same as the max heap size. Given that you're trying to create 4(?) caches with 200MB of offheap each you may well just be running out of offheap space. Try adding a suitable value when you spawn the JVM?

Comment: thank you for the hint. removing <offheap unit="MB">200</offheap> from ehcache.xml makes the jar run in Docker :)